# Spark regexp_extract() fails - Regex group count is 0, but the specified group index is 1

Tags: r, regex, apache-spark, illegalargumentexception, sparklyr

I would like to extract the last part of the string (after the last forward slash).
When I use the following code it fails with the error:

```r
library(sparklyr)
library(tidyverse)

sc <- spark_connect(method = "databricks")

tibble(my_string = c("aaa/bbb/ccc", "ddd/eee/fff", "ggg/hhh/iii")) %>%
  copy_to(sc, ., "test_regexp_extract", overwrite = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(my_result = regexp_extract(my_string, "(?<=/)[^/]*$")) %>%
  count(my_result)
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Regex group count is 0, but the
> specified group index is 1

`show_query()` shows the following query:

```
<SQL>
SELECT `my_result`, COUNT(*) AS `n`
FROM (SELECT `my_string`, regexp_extract(`my_string`, "(?<=/)[^/]*$") AS `my_result`
FROM `test_regexp_extract`) `q01`
GROUP BY `my_result`
```

I suspect it might be the problem of the forward slash character in the regex. I tried to escape it with a backslash.
Another idea is that for some reason it fails when no match is found.  According to the Spark documentation it should work though:

> If the regex did not match, or the specified group did not match, an
> empty string is returned.

Any idea why it fails? In R, the same code works fine.

Comment: So have you tried escaping the `/` : `(?<=\/)[^\/]*$` ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I tried. The error goes: 
Error : '\/' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(?<=\/"
Some(<code style = 'font-size:10p'> Error: '\/' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting &quot;&quot;(?&lt;=\/&quot; </code>)

Comment: `regexp_extract(my_string, "(?<=\\/)[^\\/]*$"))` translates into `(?<=\/)[^\/]*$` but the error is again `Regex group count is 0, but the specified group index is 1`.

Comment: I managed to make it work by using this regex `([^/]*)$` instead. Still, I would love to learn what went wrong in the original regex.

Comment: You need to specify at least one capture group in the regex pattern (just like you did in your working version `([^/]*)$`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regexp_extract` by default returns *the first group*. Your regex pattern `(?<=/)[^/]*$` has *no groups*, so this is where the problem lies. You could:

- create a group using `()`, e.g. `(?<=/)([^/]*)$`
- add `0` as the 3rd parameter to the function: `regexp_extract(my_string, "(?<=/)[^/]*$", 0)`. This way, *the full* regex match will be returned as opposed to only the first group.